# Token transfer taking very long

Tags: tokens

I am not familiar with at all with token transfers on the ETH platform, so if someone knowledgable could answer my questions, it would be greatly appreciated. A few hours ago I initiated a transfer from my Android Eidoo wallet to a trading account (an exchange). The Tx is showing in Etherscan. When refreshing the Etherscan Tx page, on the "Estimated Confirmation Duration" line, it has been showing different estimated times in minutes. It has shown 12, 9, 8, 4, 2 minutes. Then now it's back to 9 minutes.

In the wallet, when I submitted the transfer, I let the default setting at "Normal" for the "gas" speed. There are 3 "gas speed" settings in the wallet: Slow, Normal and High.

I have initiated the transfer about 15 hours ago, and it is still showing as "Pending" in the wallet and on the Etherscan page. The token transfer is : ZIL (ERC20 compatible)

The Etherscan Tx id can be seen here:

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x72adcbc73ab38f9fbb144a37337083777994fab54c3a6953f6a94dd881ca96ba

Why is it taking so long to get confirmed ? What's going on ?

In the future, what "gas setting" can I use in the Wallet to speed up the transaction?

If I ever wish to have a transfer done, let's say within 30 minutes, what should I do ?

Also, can someone can give me a rough estimate on how long (in hours) it still going to take for this transaction to be processeed (confirmed) on the network? Thank you all for answering my questions.

Comment: Eidoo wallet is annoying for me too, it takes more than 1 hour to transfer some ETH to another address... Now I know that MyEtherWallet is the best, you can send ETH and your payment reaches the address within a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to have been confirmed now. For future reference, the [ETH Gas Station](https://ethgasstation.info/) may be helpful in determining a Gas price.

Comment: Yes, indeed it is now showing in the wallet on the exchange. But why did it take so long (15 hours). Was it the "gas" fee that was not set high enough ?  I really need to know this. Thanks for any hints that you can give me.

Comment: The higher the Gas price you set, the more likely a miner is to include your transaction in the block. The price you set must have been lower than the average at the time.

Comment: I used the default gas setting in the Wallet (Normal), I thought it would be ok. Next time I'll set a higher Gas price. Thank you so much for your advice, it is much appreciated, also for the link to the Gas Station.

Comment: some time on blockchain there is more congestion (like during a big ico) so miner prefers those transactions who pay more gas price first.

Answer (score 0):

Transaction time is based on how much fee you pay to mine your transaction..
Fee =gas×gasPrice;
Generally for token transfer put gas=60000 &gasPrice=3Gwei;
For reference https://ethgasstation.info